# Ternary shortcut on Groovy

Tags: groovy

I know that the ternary operator is already a shortcut in itself, but I'm still wondering if there is a shortcut for this in `groovy`:

```
String typeFilter = (params?.type) ? params.type : ""
```

What I'm trying to do here is:

> *"If the `HashMap` `params` has a `type` key, assign the value of that key to `typeFilter`, otherwise, assign `typeFilter` with an empty string"*

I'm thinking whether if I can avoid typing `params?.type` twice, or is this the shortest code for my given scenario? Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You effectively just described the elvis operator:

```
String typeFilter = params.type ?: ""
```

More on it here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator

Just make sure you understand the Groovy truth (http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-tell-groovy-truth.html)
especially when it comes to the value of `0` vs `null` vs `empty`. Consider this:

```
params.age = 0
...
// elsewhere in the code
params.age = params.age ?: 6 // if no age provided default to 6
```

This would set the `params.age` to `6` although if was already initialized with `0`!

Comment: Hey, first time hearing it... why it's called `Elvis` operator?

Comment: Because of a hairstyle.

Comment: @Opal Whoah! I haven't notice that `?:` symbol!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the corner-case of the key `type` having a null value?  The Elvis operator will return the RHS if this happens.  This may not matter in the context of what you are trying to achieve, but it isn't correct for your requirement (taken literally):

> *"If the `HashMap` `params` has a `type` key, assign the value of that key to `typeFilter`, otherwise, assign `typeFilter` with an empty string"*

Examples.  (I've used 'none' rather than an empty string to make the output clearer.)

```
println( [:].type ?: 'none' )
=> none

println( [type: 42].type ?: 'none' )
=> 42

// But do you want null or 'none' in this case?
println( [type: null].type ?: 'none' )
=> none
```

Comment: Thanks for the concern... apparently I had already put error traps and filter before the line of code above, I just haven't included it on the question.

Comment: flawless use of elvis operator!

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by @defectus is in general correct there're some corner cases. Consider the following example:

```
def s = ''
def r = s.empty ?: 'notempty'
assert r == true
```

In the example above `true` is returned instead of empty string. While for some it might be obvious, when I face it some time ago it was a real problem ;)